# Add migration from Package Manager vs dnx

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dnx

I can add a migration from the console using dnx like so:

```
dnx . ef migration add test
```

But I can't do it via Visual Studio's Package Manager Console, using the same line above. The error I get is:

```
dnx : System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1':
At line:1 char:1
+ dnx . ef migration add test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.InvalidO...ersion=v4.5.1'::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-beta5
   EntityFramework.SqlServer 7.0.0-beta5
   ...
```

Is the PMC running for 4.5.1 and the console something else?

I would prefer to run the dnx commands from the Package Manager rather than a separate window, as we used to using `Add-Migration`...

Comment: Have you tried running "dnu restore" first? DNX commands are all launched using dnx.exe, and they should respect the target frameworks defined within your project.json. For instance, I just ran my xunit tests via the PMC by invoking "dnx . test" just fine.

Comment: Yep, ran `dnu restore`, still get the error above. How come it's always targeting DNX 4.5.1? Even if in the project properties I set it to target .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Package Manager Console wasn't in the right directory. I needed to `cd src\appname` to get into the right folder before running the `dnx` command.